# Gallery of images using ViewPager + zoom in ImageViews

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-viewpager

**What am I trying to implement?**

A *gallery* of images using ViewPager. I choose this option because the smooth transition between images (I'm using ImageView), it is nice and quite easy to implement.

**What is my problem exactly?**

I've been able to implement all this **but** zoom isn't working. I can see in *LogCat* how it's printed **ZOOM** (the code is at the end of the post) but the image is not enlarged. Just a few notes about the following code:

- `ImageViewHelperURL.setUrlDrawable((ImageView) img, url, R.drawable.no_image);` I'm using [UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) to download asynchronously the images from the web.
- `api.getListUrls()` It's an ArrayList where I have the image urls.
- I've tried also using an ImageView from R.drawable instead of downloading the image

  ```
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.graphics.Matrix;
  import android.graphics.PointF;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.ActionBar;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
  import android.support.v4.view.Menu;
  import android.support.v4.view.MenuItem;
  import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
  import android.util.FloatMath;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.MenuInflater;
  import android.view.MotionEvent;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
  import android.widget.Gallery;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  public class Slide extends FragmentActivity {
      private ViewPager mPager;
      public static Api api;
      public static int POSITION;
      public static ActionBar topbar;
      public static Context ctx;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.fragment);
          ctx = Slide.this;
          POSITION = 0;
          topbar = getSupportActionBar();

          /* get portadas */
          api = new Api();
          api.getUrlsFromAPI();

          topbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
          topbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

          mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
          mPager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
      }

      @Override
      protected void onResume() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onResume();
          mPager.setCurrentItem(POSITION);
      }

      static final class TestAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
          public TestAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
              super(fm);
          }

          @Override
          public int getCount() {
              return api.getListUrls().size();
          }

          @Override
          public Fragment getItem(int position) {
              TestFragment f = new TestFragment();

              f.url = api.getListUrls().get(position).getUrl();
              f.position = position;
              return f;
          }
      }

      public static class TestFragment extends Fragment {
          String url = "";
          Integer position = 0;

          public TestFragment() {
              setRetainInstance(true);
          }

          @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setHasOptionsMenu(true);
          }

          @Override
          public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              ImageView img = new ImageView(getActivity());

              img.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6) ;
              img.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)) ;

              ImageViewHelperURL.setUrlDrawable((ImageView) img, url, R.drawable.no_image) ;

              img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                  private static final String TAG = "SlideImageView";
                  // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
                  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                  Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

                  // We can be in one of these 3 states
                  static final int NONE = 0;
                  static final int DRAG = 1;
                  static final int ZOOM = 2;
                  int mode = NONE;

                  // Remember some things for zooming
                  PointF start = new PointF();
                  PointF mid = new PointF();
                  float oldDist = 1f;

                  @Override
                  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                      ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

                      // Dump touch event to log
                      dumpEvent(event);

                      // Handle touch events here...
                      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                          savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                          start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                          Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
                          mode = DRAG;
                          break;
                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                          oldDist = spacing(event);
                          Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                          if (oldDist > 10f) {
                              savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                              midPoint(mid, event);
                              mode = ZOOM;
                              Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                          }
                          break;
                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                          mode = NONE;
                          Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                          break;
                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                          if (mode == DRAG) {
                              // ...
                              matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                              matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                                      event.getY() - start.y);
                          } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                              float newDist = spacing(event);
                              Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                              if (newDist > 10f) {
                                  matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                  float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                                  Log.d(TAG, "ZOOOOOOOM: " + scale);
                                  matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                              }
                          }
                          break;
                      }

                      view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                      return true; // indicate event was handled
                  }

                  /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
                  private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                      String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL",
                              "OUTSIDE", "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?",
                              "8?", "9?" };
                      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                      int action = event.getAction();
                      int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
                      sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
                      if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
                              || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
                          sb.append("(pid ").append(
                                  action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
                          sb.append(")");
                      }
                      sb.append("[");
                      for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                          sb.append("#").append(i);
                          sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
                          sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
                          sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
                          if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                              sb.append(";");
                      }
                      sb.append("]");
                      Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
                  }

                  /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
                  private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
                      float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                      float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                      return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
                  }

                  /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
                  private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
                      float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
                      float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
                      point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
                  }
              });

              return img;
          }

          @Override
          public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

          }

          @Override
          public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

              return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
      }

  }
  ```

I've already tried the following tutorial with no success:

- [How to use Multi-touch in Android 2: Part 6, Implementing the Pinch Zoom Gesture](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847)

Comment: Late to this question - but if you're using a ViewPager for your gallery - you're never recycling all those fragments, right? You just keep creating new ones?

Comment: I think I'm recycling them. When you go back (to the previous activity), this one is destroyed? But I'm just a beginner in this, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use a Matrix with an ImageView to transform the image, you need to change the [scale type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29) to `ScaleType.Matrix`, otherwise there will be no effect. The default scale type is `ScaleType.FIT_CENTER` and so it will ignore the matrix.

Regarding your original task, if you get this working you may find that the touch gestures on the ImageView will interfere with the scrolling of the ViewPager. You will definitely have problems supporting single-touch drag because this directly corresponds with the natural ViewPager swipe motion to go to the next view.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the interference... However, now I'm able to zoom the image :) Do you know a better way to implement a gallery of images? Supporting zoom, of course.

Comment: I did it the exact same way. For the interference i tried to disable the fling gesture of the ViewPager. That worked great, but than i getted an index out of range error for no reason? But the reason was my overridden ViewPager, i think there is a bug in the v4 compatibility package. But i didn't found a way jat to disable the fling and just zoom. If i lift the first pointer my app crashes :(