# How to add imageURL in Viewpager in android.I need a smooth swipe action

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-ndk

How to load imageURL in viewpager?
Actually i implemented the task without pager,i used Gesture to do so,but i need to display rhe images with the help of pager. 
I had seen many examples but i cant understand,the thing is myself having array of ImageURl[],showing images in Gridview,if i clicks the particular image it should display the current image and while swiping other images should be followed.

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089380/gallery-of-images-using-viewpager-zoom-in-imageviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great Link:  https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/UniversalImageLoaderExample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader/ImagePagerActivity.java

Comment: Great Comment Mr.mountainlionmoorthy